# Converting a dplyr transformation command into a base R function

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dplyr command that works great on its own:

```
XOR1 <- XOR1 %>%
  mutate(XOR_inter = case_when(
    chr18.27348077_G == 0 & chr18.32316331_A == 0 ~ 0,
    chr18.27348077_G == 0 & chr18.32316331_A == 1 ~ 1,
    chr18.27348077_G == 0 & chr18.32316331_A == 2 ~ 0,
    chr18.27348077_G == 1 & chr18.32316331_A == 0 ~ 1,
    chr18.27348077_G == 1 & chr18.32316331_A == 1 ~ 0,
    chr18.27348077_G == 1 & chr18.32316331_A == 2 ~ 1,
    chr18.27348077_G == 2 & chr18.32316331_A == 0 ~ 0,
    chr18.27348077_G == 2 & chr18.32316331_A == 1 ~ 1,
    chr18.27348077_G == 2 & chr18.32316331_A == 2 ~ 0
  ))
```

Basically, it checks for two conditionals in the column names (chr18.27348077_G & chr18.32316331_A) and outputs a desired value into a new column based on the combination of these columns' values. It works perfectly but I want to convert this heavy code into a function I can call within a loop. I tried to convert it as follows:

```
FunXOR <- function(df, X1, X2) {
  df <- df %>%
    mutate(XOR_inter = case_when(
      X1 == 0 & X2 == 0 ~ 0,
      X1 == 0 & X2 == 1 ~ 1,
      X1 == 0 & X2 == 2 ~ 0,
      X1 == 1 & X2 == 0 ~ 1,
      X1 == 1 & X2 == 1 ~ 0,
      X1 == 1 & X2 == 2 ~ 1,
      X1 == 2 & X2 == 0 ~ 0,
      X1 == 2 & X2 == 1 ~ 1,
      X1 == 2 & X2 == 2 ~ 0
    ))
}

FunXOR(XOR1, "chr18.27348077_G", "chr18.32316331_A")
```

It runs without an error but nothing happens (i.e. no new column in generated). I've read that dplyr syntax doesn't work great with normal R function syntax. I was hoping to get help in converting this to a function for ease of use later

Comment: I expect it should work if you put `{{ }}` around your `X1` and `X2` references. eg. `{{X1}} == 0 & {{X2}} == 0 ~ 0,`.  Background here: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html

Comment: I actually tried that, Jon. It didn't work unfortunately

Comment: If your variables only contain `0`,`1`,`2` then you can simplify your code to `as.integer(abs(X1 - X2) == 1)`.

Comment: Good point, Ritchie! Thanks!

Comment: Glad it worked for you eventually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `{{var}}` to pass unquoted variable names.

Additionally, if you want to update your `data.frame` instead of outputting to the console, you can assign to the current `data.frame`.

```r
library(dplyr)

XOR1 <- data.frame(
  chr18.27348077_G = c(0,1,2),
  chr18.32316331_A = c(0,1,2)
)

FunXOR <- function(df, X1, X2) {
  df <- df %>%
    mutate(XOR_inter = case_when(
      {{X1}} == 0 & {{X2}} == 0 ~ 0,
      {{X1}} == 0 & {{X2}} == 1 ~ 1,
      {{X1}} == 0 & {{X2}} == 2 ~ 0,
      {{X1}} == 1 & {{X2}} == 0 ~ 1,
      {{X1}} == 1 & {{X2}} == 1 ~ 0,
      {{X1}} == 1 & {{X2}} == 2 ~ 1,
      {{X1}} == 2 & {{X2}} == 0 ~ 0,
      {{X1}} == 2 & {{X2}} == 1 ~ 1,
      {{X1}} == 2 & {{X2}} == 2 ~ 0
    ))
  return(df)
}

FunXOR <- FunXOR(XOR1, chr18.27348077_G, chr18.32316331_A)
```

The returned value with this sample data is:

```r
> FunXOR(XOR1, chr18.27348077_G, chr18.32316331_A)
  chr18.27348077_G chr18.32316331_A XOR_inter
1                0                0         0
2                1                1         0
3                2                2         0
```

Comment: So there's two issues I can see with either of these approaches, the first is that it just outputs the dataframe in the console instead of updated the dataframe. The second is that the function doesn't work. The XOR_inter column should contain 1's and 0's

Comment: The first issue can easily be mitigated by just using 
XOR1 <- FunXOR(XOR1, "chr18.27348077_G", "chr18.32316331_A")
But the second, and more important issue, persists. I appreciate the help though!

Comment: I just updated the post - check it out.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. It was a combination of using the {{var}} and return(df). What's interesting is that I used XOR1 <- FunXOR(XOR1, chr18.27348077_G, chr18.32316331_A) instead of FunXOR <- FunXOR(XOR1, chr18.27348077_G, chr18.32316331_A) because I believe that just overwrites the function. But it works! Thanks!